# Algorithm analyse with Big-Theta notation

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Is
$(n \log n) + \frac{\lfloor (\log n)^2\rfloor + \log n}{2} = \Theta(n \log n)$ ?

My solution:
$$
  \begin{aligned}
    c_1 \cdot (n \log n) \le\,& (n \log n) + \frac{\lfloor(\log n)^2\rfloor + \log n}{2} \le c_2 \cdot (n \log n) &(\text{Divide by } n \log n)\\
    c_1 \cdot 1 \le\,& 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left\lfloor \frac{\log n + 1}{n} \right\rfloor \le c_2 \cdot 1 
  \end{aligned}
$$

I choosed $c_1 = 1$ so 1 is always $\le (1 + x + y )$ for $x,y \ge 0$ and 
$c_2 = 4 \ge ( 1 + x + y )$ for  $0 < x,y < 1$.

So $(n \log n) + \frac{\lfloor(\log n)^2\rfloor + \log n}{2} = \Theta(n \log n)$.

Is my solution right?

Comment: Hi, I took the liberty of reformatting your question using LaTeX to make it more readable. Could you please check if my translation is corect?

Comment: The result of the division is not correct, unless I misinterpreted the `[x]` notation. Note that in general, $\lfloor a \rfloor / b \neq \lfloor a/b \rfloor$. Also, I don't understand where the $x$ and $y$ are coming from - what exactly are you trying to say there?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not correct, because it treats  floor brackets as if they were parentheses.

General suggestion: deal with one inequality at a time. As follows:

**Step 1** is to exhibit $c_1$ such that 
$$
c_1 n\log n\le (n \log n) + \frac{\lfloor (\log n)^2\rfloor + \log n}{2}  
\tag{1}$$
Clearly, $c_1=1$ works in (1).

**Step 2** is to exhibit $c_2$ such that 
$$
 (n \log n) + \frac{\lfloor (\log n)^2\rfloor + \log n}{2}  \le c_2 n\log n 
\tag{2}$$
To this end, use the inequalities $\lfloor x \rfloor  \le x$ and $\log n\le n$:
$$
\frac{\lfloor (\log n)^2\rfloor + \log n}{2}  \le 
\frac{ (\log n)^2  + \log n}{2} \le \frac{ n\log n   + \log n}{2} \le n\log n   
$$
Hence, $c_2=2$ works in (2).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to show that
$\frac{\lfloor (\log n)^2\rfloor + \log n}{2}
= o(n \log n)$.

This is a special case
of the general principle that
if $g(n) = o(f(n))$
then
$f(n) + g(n)
=
\Theta(f(n))
$.
Try to prove this. Do not make the proof too hard.